# How to determine if two mutable data structures are the same?

Tags: data-structures

How can I determine if two mutable data structures ([`DataStructure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataStructure.html)) are truly the same? I do not mean checking if they have the same value. I mean checking if they are the same data structure, i.e. whether they both respond to mutation.

Example:

```
a = CreateDataStructure["Value", 1];

b = a["Copy"];

c = b;
```

Now `b` and `c` are the same, but `a` and `b` are different. They merely hold the same value. `a === b` tests if the value if the same, and therefore returns `True`.

But mutating `a` does not mutate `b`. The variables `a` and `b` do not point to the same data structure.

```
a["Set", 2]
(* 2 *)

{a["Get"], b["Get"]}
(* {2, 1} *)
```

`b` and `c` do point to the same data structure:

```
b["Set", 5]
(* 5 *)

{b["Get"], c["Get"]}
(* {5, 5} *)
```

Comment: Maybe try something like `GroupBy[{a, b, c}, Hash]`

Comment: If you're in a <12.1 environment you can use any internal function that knows about this distinction, e.g. make a ``Language`ExpressionStore`` (the memory will clean itself up automatically if you do) and then attach a UUID to each `Expr` that you can check against.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This way of comparison is not directly exposed in top-level at the moment.

However, it could be done through the compiler, for example

```
sameInstanceQ = 
  FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[e1, "Expression"], Typed[e2, "Expression"]}, 
    Native`SameInstanceQ[e1, e2]]];

a = CreateDataStructure["Value", 1];
b = a["Copy"];
c = b;

SameQ[a, b, c]

(* True *)

sameInstanceQ[a, b]

(* False *)

sameInstanceQ[b, c]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

A new entry in the function repository, [`SameInstanceQ`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SameInstanceQ), can also be used here:

```
In[31]:= a = CreateDataStructure["Value", 1];
b = a["Copy"];
c = b;

In[34]:= ResourceFunction["SameInstanceQ"][a, b]

Out[34]= False

In[36]:= ResourceFunction["SameInstanceQ"][b, c]

Out[36]= True
```

It can also work with normal Wolfram Language expressions and is not limited to data structures:

```
In[42]:= a = <|"a" -> 1|>;
b = <|"a" -> 1|>;
c = b;

In[45]:= ResourceFunction["SameInstanceQ"][a, b]

Out[45]= False

In[46]:= ResourceFunction["SameInstanceQ"][b, c]

Out[46]= True
```

This function exposes some internal implementation details that are interesting, like the fact that there is only one version of an empty association:

```
In[47]:= ResourceFunction["SameInstanceQ"][<||>, <||>]

Out[47]= True
```

Other corner cases are discussed on the ref page.